# How to pass binary image to image handler to display it in DataList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, httphandler

I have a web page with a method called to display some images in the `DataList` control

MyImage.cs

```
class MyImage
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    byte[] Jpeg { get; set; } 
}
```

MyImages.aspx.cs

```
public void DisplayMyImages(IEnumerable<MyImage> myImages)
{
    this.myImagesDataList.DataSource = myImages;
    this.myImagesDataList.DataBind();  
}

/// ...

protected void myImagesDataList_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        MyImage myImage = (MyImage)e.Item.DataItem;
        Image myImageImage = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("myImageImage");

        // How to pass myImage.Jpeg to ImageHandler? form here

        myImageImage.ImageUrl = "~/Handlers/ImageHandler.ashx";
    }
}
```

But how to pass jpeg image to `ImageHandler` if it is already extracted from the database and passed to `DisplayMyImages()` function?

Remarks:

I do not want to save them back to files and pass the paths in a query string to `ImageHandler`

Having a standard query string approach is not possible as I do not want to violate model view presenter approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just answered [your question on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/4405799/How-to-pass-binary-image-to-image-handler-to-displ.aspx), but I'll copy the answer here as well.

Depending on how big your images are, and which browsers you need to support, you might be able to use a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Web_browser_support).

```
myImageImage.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(myImage.Jpeg);
```

*(If you're using IE8, you're limited to 32Kb; earlier versions of IE aren't supported at all.)*

Comment: though I found it easier to save images to disk and assign url to image control

Comment: you approach is really ingenious! I was struggled with session to be used with http handler, then I resorted to saving images to disk and supplying links, but yours is quite distinct!

Answer (score 2):

Normaly image should be produced by ImageHandler not passed to, so just flip your logic.
You will end up with something like this:

```
myImageImage.ImageUrl = "~/Handlers/ImageHandler.aspx?id=yourImageId";
```

Make sure you set correct content type, something like this:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
```

And this is how you write your image to response:

```
byte[] fileData = null;
//TODO: load your image data into fileData!
context.Response.BinaryWrite(fileData);
```

Comment: I know that passing id via query string is the usual method but in model view presenter view is provided with the data, worse thing is to couple image handler that has no concern to the view coupled with presenter

Comment: Dont you have some kind of unique id provided with image data from datasource?

Comment: the data is already extracted. I'm looking for alternative means of passing image data to image handler. coupling image handler to presenter will need certain modifications which might be impossible

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to pass in the ID of the image and retrieve this directly from the DB when required and use code similiar to ;

```
var data = //Code to retrieve byte[];

int len = data.Length;
response.ContentType = "image/png";
response.BinaryWrite(data);
```

Comment: it is not possible in my situation of model view presenter architecture

Comment: Adding an ID and passing this into a dedicated handler is probably going to be the only option you can use, and in my opinion (and that of others on here it seems) is going to be best way. The only other option to to pass in the image data in the querystring and you are probably  going to hit issues with querystring length in this scenario.

Comment: what about session or public properties of the image handler? I can not use image handler with a query string since image data is already extracted form database

Comment: I would also add that adding the ID to your image class and using it appropriately is not going to break any architecture. If it does, it is not the right one for your application.

Comment: I need to pass data to image handler without using a query string

Comment: Implement IRequiresSessionState on your Handler and you will be able to access Session data, you can then read in whatever you need to. Poor design imo, but should work.

Comment: or may be create aspx page instead of the handler to access the session state?

Answer (score 0):

First of all i think you may going wrong

```
myImageImage.ImageUrl = "~/Handlers/ImageHandler.aspx";
```

NOTE: you need to include ImageHandler file with `.ashx` not `.aspx` file. `.ashx Generic Handler` that works as image on context while retrieving image from ImageHandler. Here is the correct form of ImageHandler file.

```
imgProfile.ImageUrl = "ImageHandler.ashx?imgid=" + imageId.ToString();
```

[click here to see complete referece.](http://www.dotnetlogix.com/Article/aspnet/194/Save-and-retrieve-image-to-and-from-database-in-aspnet.html)

Hope, It may helps you. !!

Comment: I actually use ashx just mistyped it. there is no way in model view presenter to couple image handler to the service to extract the image with a query string

Comment: ohh, it's ok. look at this this example (http://farazkhanhighoncsharp.blogspot.in/2011/04/ashx-generic-handler-in-aspnet.html)

Comment: yes, generic aspx handler, I was thinking that we only solution was to save images to files and set urls

Comment: but the over problem is that my aspx handler is not invoked after I set ImageUrl